# AngularJS get certain parameters from $resource query request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-formly

I have object which I retrieved like this `$scope.posts = posts.query()`

**posts** is ngResrouce

```
angular.module('flapperNews')
.factory('posts', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('api/posts.json/:id', {id: "@id"})
}]);
```

**Retrieved object**

```
[
        0: {
            $hasKey: "object:4",
            title: "some text",
            content: "hello world there",
            upvotes: 0
        }
        1: {
            $hasKey: "object:5",
            title: "Lorem ipsum is dolor",
            content: "hello world there",
            upvotes: 0
        }
        2: {
            $hasKey: "object:6",
            title: "When there is nothing to share",
            content: "hello world there",
            upvotes: 0
        }
    ]
```

How can I get just "titles" from this retrieved object so I can use it for 
AngularJS Formly validation? (validating if the new post title would be unique)